# How to keep sort order in a new array php

Tags: php, sorting

I have

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
  foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    if ($value1['Id'] == $value2['Ref']) {
        $result[] = $value2 + $value1;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I keep `$result` in the same order as `$array2`?

Comment: Please add the content of `$array2`, the expected result and what result you're currently getting to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this php function with `array_multisort`:

```
<?php
$ar1 = array(10, 100, 100, 0);
$ar2 = array(1, 3, 2, 4);
array_multisort($ar1, $ar2);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I used multisort